# Symfony Max Allowable Size Error

Tags: php, symfony1

I just scaffolded a new module and when I save using the generated form I get:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 8388608 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 19456 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ats/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Hydrator/Graph.php on line 404

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

symfony is quite greedy for memory, so this sometimes happens. You can increase the memory available to PHP/symfony via php.ini as suggested above:

*php.ini*:

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

128M here is just an example, but one which you might need to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

because that's the configured memory limit of your php.  you may want to find what `php.ini` it uses from `phpinfo()` and edit it to give symfony more memory.

Answer (score 0):

The [`memory_limit`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) is the maximum amount of memory a PHP script is allowed to use. Basically, this is a security configuration option, to ensure you don't have a PHP script that does mad and consumes all the memory of the server -- or worse, that you don't have several PHP script that eat more memory than the server has.

This configuration directive can be set in the `php.ini` file ; it's the file that sets the configuration of PHP.

To find out where the `php.ini` file is on your server, you can use the [`phpinfo()`](http://fr.php.net/phpinfo) function : somewhere near the top of the output, there should be a "`Loaded Configuration File`" option.

Which value should be used for memory_limit is an interesting question... In the past, when we were only writting small script, `8MB` was generally enough.

Now, with Frameworks, bigger applications structured in layers, ORM, and all that, `8MB` is generally not enough *(as you obviously noticed)* -- I generally set `memory_limit` to `32M` on my production servers, which is almost always enough for my applications, without being *too much*.

So, in my `php.ini` file, I have :

```
memory_limit = 32M
```

Note : it would be tempting to put a very high value for `memory_limit`, to just get rid of the problem... But remember that `memory_limit` is here as a security : you should make sure your server has enough memory to answer several requests at the same time !